# Why is the earliest allowed birthdate 1/1/1920?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, age

I was doing a little poking around my profile, and when changing my birthdate I discovered a limitation:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> - Birthday must be after 1920/01/01

Okay, so that means the oldest valid age on Stack Overflow is **95**. At first glance, that might seem to be sufficient.

However, according to [recent population estimates by the U.S Census Bureau](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/PEP/2013/PEPSYASEXN), there were **510,773 people** above the age of 94 living in the U.S in 2013. That's in the U.S. alone, and I'm fairly sure there are plenty more around the world.

So it seems that Stack Exchange may have missed a key demographic when they set the birthdate limitation. It feels wrong to deny our elders the ability to ask questions, just like the rest of us.

I'm Santa, so I'm pretty old, but I still have questions and answers to offer. I feel like a liar not being able to put my correct birthdate of 244 AD into my Stack Overflow profile.

I'd hate to have to put any Stack Exchange associates on my naughty list, but I'll do what I have to do.

If you'd like to help protest against this atrocity, change your birthdate to 1/1/1920 such that your age is seen as `95`.

Comment: On MSE: [Age limit is too strict](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66384/age-limit-is-too-strict)

Comment: Imo, _"key demographic"_ is a gross overstatement. Sure, there are probably some people over 94 (!!!) that would want to ask questions SO, but I wouldn't be surprised if that number of people could be counted on 2 hands. I'm not saying it's a bad idea to change the min. date, just that your reason to do so is flawed.

Comment: Filling in your age is **optional**. Any late nonagenarians can just put their age in their About Me instead if they are keen on everyone knowing what age they are.

Comment: To put more coal to the engine, I can point out that the phenomenon of staying alive beyond the age of 94 isn't strictly limited to USA. There are, in fact, places where people reach 95 years delivered not currently under American administration, so the demographic is actually quite larger. (On the contrary note I can point out that said demographics has lived major part of their lives without computers as an active part of their day. And I find it doubtful that such an interest is widely developed during the fall of one's existence. But who knows - there might be a bunch of geezers coding...)

Comment: "It feels wrong to deny our elders the ability to ask questions, just like the rest of us." is entering your date of birth now a requirement to ask questions?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Not being able to enter their valid birthdate will likely be taken as a sign that they are not welcome.

Comment: @SantaClaus: Really? Until now I did not even know there was such a field. Also I have no incentive at all to fill this field.

Comment: @SantaClaus: I feel you're ___Massively___ overstating how much of a problem this is. If the few people of that age that have enough interest in SO to want to post here try to register, I'm pretty sure they have the common sense not to be bothered by a age field. I imagine it'd give them a chuckle, actually: _"Didn't expect someone of my age, did ya?"_ You're portraying this "Problem" as something that seriously affects a lot of users. That's simply not the case.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't tink OP implies that it's an issue affecting strongly a vast number of potential users. I think they're just flabbergasted that such a limitation exists. Also, they find it peculiar as to why this particular limit's been set.

Comment: _"a key demographic"_, _"deny our elders"_... Yea, he's exaggerating a bit, @KonradViltersten. Most sites where you enter a date of birth use dropdowns or calendars as input. Most of those are limited.

Comment: This is the nicest kind of bug - one that fixes itself. Just wait for ~20 years, it won't me an issue anymore.

Comment: +1. For Santa. You monsters. (As a side note, assuming birthdates are stored as integers that are really long anyway -measuring seconds probably-, is limiting them to post-1/1/1920 that much of a gain?).

Comment: Is the 1920 date fixed?  Or does it roll so it is consistently 94 years ago?

Comment: @mcalex: On the [MSE topic from 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66384/193139), it was also 1920-01-01.

Comment: If you're a 94 year-old programmer, you're likely a Master and a Professor and wouldn't spend time here anyway.  Btw, Santa I knew you existed all along.

Comment: I find the answers quite amusing but they don't answer the question at all, so why on earth did 12 and 41 people upvote them? Anyone that can provide a _real_ answer?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo As you said, people found them quite amusing, which is likely the reason they upvoted them.

Comment: Should we have a meta-meta-stackoverflow to ask if upvoting funny but otherwise unuseful content on meta answers is ok? :D

Comment: @ivy_lynx Measuring seconds for a date? I'd rather measure days...

Comment: @glglgl Please understand context before trying to be clever. Time in software is most often measured in seconds or milliseconds, hence my _assumption_, not _suggestion_ on how they're measured. If they are indeed storing the particular data as days, it only strengthens my actual argument that it isn't much of a gain.

Comment: We don't ask for this information anymore, so closing this. Glad to have it out of the way!

Answer (score 30):

It's because they don't want questions tagged as [babbage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babbage), [jacquard-loom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jacquard-loom), [eniac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eniac) or [dead-moth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dead-moth). Anyone that old will have expertise in those technologies, and will be happy to answer them to further enrich the site.

Comment: What's wrong with [tag:jacquard-loom]? The [Ontario Science Centre](http://www.ontariosciencecentre.ca/Tour/Volunteer-Demonstrations/) has one that still works, and there are rugs hanging all over the building that were made with it.

Comment: I'm going to start tagging my questions with `Abacus` and see if I can coax some of these old codgers away from their shuffleboard.

Comment: I have expertise in setting up the program drum on an 029 key punch - it was a skill I used many times. I don't feel the slightest urge to create a `program-drum` tag. Any 95+ age people here would be asking and answering on topics they are learning, or have used recently.

Answer (score 5):

It should clearly be possible.

With the amount of other possibly live-supporting places in this solar system and the amount of exo-planets we find these days its only a matter of time some alien pops by and is offended for not being able to enter his birthday (or hatchday or whatever) correctly.

I mean seriously, an interstellar slower than light (but still very fast) travel takes decades, maybe even centuries for both the start and the endpoint (although not the traveller).

So if after having listened to [our](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/) [broadcasts](http://xkcd.com/1212/) they could start vessels (if only to mute us) with passengers. If they started ~50 years ago from 50 lightyears away (thus having listened to some of the first broadcasts we sent out) they could very well be older tan 1920.

Comment: Gives the parentheses much more meaning, doesn't it? ;)

Comment: The day my Java questions get answered by an alien, I'm leaving this site for good.

Comment: @DavidWallace Interesting that you single out Java questions as being used by aliens.  I certainly hope that no human wrote [this](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition).

Comment: @MosheKatz [Looks like an alien](https://github.com/Mikkeren) to me