# How much longer can one reproduce?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I have always felt that the close reason "caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced" was a bit awkward. The wording "no longer" suggests that the problem was demonstrably reproducible,  and indeed reproduced, up to a certain point and then stopped being reproducible. This is not something I can usually judge; I have no idea what the OP was doing in their private time before posting on Stack Overflow; presumably the problem was never reproducible in the first place.

Would any meaning be lost if we simplified the first part of ths close reason into:

> This question was caused by a problem that cannot be reproduced

Or:

> The problem described in this question cannot be reproduced, or it is due to a simple typographical error.

Or even:

> Not reproducible, or trivial.

This simpler phrasing would make this rather important close reason much easier to find, and it would also correspond more closely to traditional bug tracking close reasons (e.g. "working as intended", "not reproducible", "invalid").

Comment: I was going to take offense at the question title here, but decided that it's probably not meant in a personal way ;)

Comment: Trying too hard not to say "Too Localized"?.

Comment: In addition to simplifying the wording I would swap the reasons around so that the *due to a typo* reason was listed first as it's the most common.

Comment: @HansPassant: No, really not. "Too localized" is a vague reason that says something like "nobody is interested in thinking about the specific situation you claim to be in". By contrast, "not reproducible" is a straight-forward statement that I think the described problem doesn't exist.

Comment: [Looks like its 96](https://ca.shine.yahoo.com/blogs/shine-on/indian-man-becomes-world-oldest-dad-96-claims-200627108.html)

Comment: Could not Reproduce  - http://xkcd.com/583/ :)

Comment: I'd really hate having "trivial" as one of the close reasons. There are so many things that seem trivial to some people...

Comment: @eis: That's a good point, I meant it only as a shortening of the second phrase. I'd probably want that second phrase as the printed reason, too. It's still succinct, but also detailed.

Comment: That topic title...I almost had my coffee come out of my nose ;-)

Comment: Very catchy title :)

Comment: *[Template comment referencing title wit.]*

Comment: @paqogomez [Don't worry, we won't have any 96 year olds around here until _next_ year](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266470/why-is-the-earliest-allowed-birthdate-1-1-1920).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you simply can't reproduce the problem then you're using the wrong close reason.  There *is* a close reason for when you simply can't reproduce a problem that the OP has:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

(emphasis mine)

The close reason you gave is for when the OP says something like, "oh, the problem went away when I cleared the cache," in a comment.

Comment: Oh, I never use that reason for the situation you describe in the last paragraph.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, that's what it's there for.

Comment: That other close reason doesn't say that that the problem cannot be reproduced, but rather that the post doesn't include *short code* that reproduces the problem. I can often reproduce a problem that's described without code. What I'm looking for is a close reason for a described problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @KerrekSB You can use a custom reason if you really want.  The question would also technically fall under "unclear what you're asking" if you would prefer that.

Comment: I'm thinking of a question like this: "I have code `int x = 0; printf("%d", x);`, and the output is `1`. Why?". There's code, and the question is clear, but it's just not a real problem. How to close it? "Not reproducible" seems perfect, and is a standard response. I shouldn't need to write a custom reason for that.

Comment: @KerrekSB If you really want a close reason that says *exactly* what you think the problem is, to a tee, then use a custom close reason.  All of the non-custom close reasons will be, by necessity, generalized to the point that they won't always be 100% on the money as to the problems with the question.  I've given you two reasons that both apply, but also include wording covering other types of situations.  Which you choose is entirely up to you.

Comment: @KerrekSB: As far as "the post doesn't include short code that reproduces the problem", if there's code but it does not reproduce the problem, then by definition it is not short code that reproduces the problem. So that close reason is accurate.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: OK, that certainly makes sense. I might argue that that's bringing in the desired meaning in a somewhat pedantic way ("Yes, I know the time, thanks for asking."), but I can't deny that the reason covers that.

Answer (score 13):

No, I think it's fine.

- You're thinking of the "needs a minimal testcase" close reason. Use that.
- "Can no longer be reproduced" is essentially an alternative to accepting an answer, for cases where the Q&A is far too localised and should just go away, usually due to the OP's problem magically going away after a reboot or after someone left a clever comment that pointed out a stupid mistake.

Comment: How does account an answer given that pushed the debugging just that little step further that then finally as "answered" the need of the question went away? Like the answer where the typo is?

Comment: @hakre: Sorry but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: For your second point, when the answer is given in a far too localized case. Is it OK in your opinion to close-vote after the answer has been given? That is: Does the *"can no longer be reproduced"* count *because* the (far too localized) answer has been given?

Comment: @hakre: Yeah, sometimes. The situation hasn't changed just because an answer was given, but the answer has _revealed_ the truth of the situation. e.g. an answer that says "you wrote `i` instead of `j`". We should certainly close such questions that have been revealed to have only that silly kind of mistake.

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted to know. And nice argument btw..

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it this scenario the close reason is well fitting?:

- A user asks a question: Why this not working. It's urgently, then drops code and leaves a nice outro like *"Help me before my brain explodes"*
- Another user spots the error like a missing character in the variable name or a missing comma. Punches in the answer: *"Try this"* shortly drops one line of code.
- The user asking the question is totally happy and comments: *"Thanks, works now!"*

So this is where it's only left to close the question as: Can't be reproduced any longer. Sure also the deserved down-vote as the material is of superior uselessness now, it has already over-lived it's time. The reason to ask the question has just disappeared. The (two) persons who were interested (the one asking and the one answering) don't have any interest in this Q&A any longer.

Comment: I'd say that scenario is nicely covered by the second part, "was due to a simple typographic error". If that's the only problem, then it was and remains reproducible, it's just not very interesting.

Comment: I think that sentece is a mere clarification in which sense reprodcueibility was to be expected. You could foster on what a typographic error actually is and what not then. Doesn't it touch logic when a different name is used or is that still a typographic error?

Comment: You can say this about any question. When it's solved, the error can no longer be reproduced.