# Why was age removed from the new User Page?

Tags: discussion, bug, profile-page, age

Since the new User Page was introduced a few days ago, I've noticed that we can no longer see the user's age. Any reason why? Or am I the only one?

Comment: It's not there. Not sure why. I [noticed this as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250970/244519), but no response yet.

Comment: [I posted as well on the age missing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250634/178816)

Comment: ughh, and you guys posted it since march. actually how long is this _new user page_ has been implemented? mine just changed 2 days ago?

Comment: @Baby , It was [released on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) months ago. Most of the other communties [got the new design 2 days ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list).

Comment: @CoolGuy ahh I see!. not been really active on MSE

Comment: You can still see it on the stack exchange network profile: http://stackexchange.com/users/3354520/baby. Not sure if that profile view is going to be modified with the design updates or not though.

Comment: Probably because of Santa Claus :)  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266470/215552

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253460 , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features/250634#250634

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Age discrimination is a problem in the programming profession.  You're considered over the top when you are thirty-something.  This inspires SO users to lie about their age when they enter it in their profile.  There are entirely too many 95 year old users for example.  Also on the low-end, COPPA rules forbid creating an account when you're younger than 13.  The Autobiographer badge in particular did not help, you used to only get it when you completed the entire profile.

The data is corrupted so no point in displaying it.

Btw, your user name suggests that you are familiar with this :)

Comment: There are [750 people](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/302876/392646/#graph) with an age of 100.

Comment: But I absolutely agree that this was worthless information that I'm glad to see go.

Comment: I completely disagree with this answer, removing something purely because people might lie about isn't a good excuse. Also, you can see see the users age by clicking "Network Profile", this just makes it more inconvenient to get to it. If you think everyone is lying about their age I don't see why they would truthfully fill out the "About Me" section, shall that go to?

Comment: @gunr2171 actually you if looked closely at the result age-count table there are 750 people with an age of 95

Comment: @Spencer, sorry but I must agree with Hans on this one. Filling in About Me is useful for anyone who's here (at least in part) to network to find employment opportunities. There's no down side to being honest if you're only seeking opportunities which are a good match for you. Unfortunately there IS a huge downside to giving your age. It shouldn't be this way, but too many people pre-judge.Officially age discrimination is frowned upon, but in reality tell that to someone >50 or <25 who will be judged on being "too old" or "too inexperienced" respectively. Better to say nothing.

Comment: I agree with @SpencerWieczorek about this. If the data is inherently corrupt why collect it at all? And what about other possibly corrupt profile data? The profile is what the user chooses to display about himself/herself. None of it is guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: I guess I agree with @spencer and @ EJP too. so should I not mark this as accepted answer because I disagree with it? :D

Comment: Eek, don't accept age discrimination man, it is totally uncool.

Comment: @Hans, I personally have been the recipient of age discrimination and there is nothing you can do about it.  The reality is, folks can always come up with reasons for not (a) hiring you, (b) giving you the contract, that sound reasonable.